# Loader reference to handle the react error

Tags: reactjs, loader, es6-module-loader

When i try implementing the following code

```js
const handleClick = (click) => {
  let result = {};
  const output = Object.keys(value)?.map((ele) => {
    if (ele === click) result[ele] = true;
    else result[ele] = false;
  });
  setValue(result);
};
```

getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMzmb.jpg). Please help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator is very new a lot of tooling doesn't support it. I would suggest updating your node version as well as running `npm update`. You also might need to update your babel config to support the syntax.

Comment: I actually dont have access to run the npx-create-react-app command an  use the loaders , so is there any loader that have to refer it.

Comment: Have added the following command in tsconfig.json  {
    "target": "ES5",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ES6", "DOM.Iterable", "ScriptHost", "ES2016.Array.Include"],
    // ...
}

Comment: thank you so much yes as u said it's a very new feature and was not supported on my project as here the node file used is not the updated one. Later simplifying my map function it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: If my answer answered your question, could you please accept it?